# Авторизация в gmail с помощью selenium

Tags: python, selenium, автоматизация

Не могу выполнить вход с помощью своих старых аккаунтов (1 год), в то время как с только что зарегистрированных входит на ура . Вот что выдает не в зависимости от правильности пароля. Запуск через webdriver.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего старые акки уже тю-тю.  Попробуйте зайти с хрома просто через логин. Я в свои старые тестовые акки и через восстановление, даже вводя правильные "паспортные" данные не смог попасть.

Comment: Все работает , только при таких обстоятельствах не входит

Comment: Тогда ищите способ перехватить ответ от гугла и гуглите по тому ответу который он присылает. А в окне может выводиться не  идеальный перевод  сообщения сервера. Мне честно говоря переход по ссылке "подробнее" нечасто помогал, но все-же стоит там порыться. Может на чат выйдете  где эту тему пользователи с суглсаппортерами  обсуждают. Естественно напрямую в саппорт смысла нет писать если у вас не коммерческие акки (или как их там называют).